# Asynchronous testing in karma for a Geocoder google maps service written in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I wrote down a Google Maps Initializer service that loads the google maps in dom and exposes the google variable. I also wrote a geocoder service and here is the code for the service.
The geoCodeAddress method is where the logic is, other parts are just typescript boilerplate. When the mapService exposes the google variable, I utilize it to define the method and geocode the given address, appropriately returning the promise for other devs to use.

```
module portal.common {

    export interface IGeoCoderService {
        geoCodeAddress(address: string): angular.IPromise<google.maps.GeocoderResult>;
    }

    export class GeoCoderService implements IGeoCoderService {
        public static $inject = ['$q', 'GoogleMapsInitializerService'];

        private $q: angular.IQService;
        public mapService: common.GoogleMapsInitializerService;
        public geocoder: google.maps.Geocoder;

        constructor(private q: angular.IQService, googleMaps: common.GoogleMapsInitializerService) {
            this.mapService = googleMaps;
            this.$q = q;
        }

        public geoCodeAddress(address: string) {
            return this.mapService.init()
                .then(() => {
                    this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    let deferred = this.$q.defer();
                    this.geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, (results: Array<google.maps.GeocoderResult>, status: google.maps.GeocoderStatus) => {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {
                            deferred.resolve(results);
                        } else {
                            deferred.reject({
                                data: 'No Results'
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                });
        }
    }

    angular.module('olCommon').service('GeoCoderService', GeoCoderService);
}
```

I'm trying to test the service using the following code which is mainly my question is how to test it correctly ? I'm failing using the given code. The second test fails because the promise is not resolved and the expectation ran earlier, hence getting undefined in the error.

```
describe('GeoCoderService', function () {
    var GeoCoderService, $timeout;

    beforeEach(module('olCommon'));

    beforeEach(function () {
        inject(function (_GeoCoderService_, _$timeout_) {
            GeoCoderService = _GeoCoderService_;
            $timeout = _$timeout_;

            spyOn(GeoCoderService, 'geoCodeAddress').and.callThrough();
        });
    });

    it('should initialize correctly', function () {
        expect(GeoCoderService).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should geocode the address correctly', function () {
        var address = 'Unit 11 35, Crown Street, Granville, NSW 2142';
        var results = undefined;
        GeoCoderService.geoCodeAddress(address).then(function (response) {
            results = response;
        });
        expect(results).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `q` will never call your `then` immediately, it actually waits for the next javascript cycle, using `setTimeout` with value 0.

And because the Angular guys knew that, they created $q that wrapps q for testing purposes.

All you have to do is:

```
rootScope.$apply();
```

Event better, do it in the `afterEach` section.

One more thing (Not related to the question), when define a private/public/protected members in the constructor TypeScript will save you the boilerplate of what you did. You code should look like this:

```
export class GeoCoderService implements IGeoCoderService {
  public geocoder: google.maps.Geocoder;

  public static $inject = ['$q', 'GoogleMapsInitializerService'];
  constructor(private q: angular.IQService, googleMaps: common.GoogleMapsInitializerService) {
  }
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: I tried doing the `afterEach(function() { $rootScope.$apply(); })` . But didn't work for me, It still says `undefined` not `defined` for second test. Yeah I refactored as per your suggestion, that's a good observation. Thanks :)

Comment: I just noticed that you did not truly mock the service, and you are calling the real service that will take some time to get resolved (Really loading the map data), you should inject a mock that will return a resolved promise.

Comment: Here is the link to my 4 files which I used. https://gist.github.com/piyushchauhan2011/a37352df8feca8f32dc2. Inject a mock ?

Comment: It depends on what are you tyring to test. I'm guessing that you are trying to test your wrapper, mock the real service, and just return a resolved promise with a mocked value... Just like you are not going to test $http, don't test google. And sometimes libraries already come with a test-kit for this exactly.

Comment: So I just mock google service and return a fake result, that can geocode an address ?

Comment: I updated the gist: https://gist.github.com/piyushchauhan2011/a37352df8feca8f32dc2 and mocked the promise call with `$q.when({})`. I understand though, but I wanted to get the results and verify the latitude and longitude for a given address.

Comment: If you could have a look at gist and comment for any possible changes, that would be awesome @gilamran

Comment: I usually build my tests in TDD, without it, it's just tests to cover holes... You don't want to test google's results, you should have a mock that will return what you expect, (when someone calls a function on this mock). This will ensure that you called what you wanted, this is what you test, YOUR logic, YOUR calling parameters, and the order of execution (Logic). not google's.

Comment: I'm 90% positive that you're trying to do something that someone already done. Just search "Google Maps api in Angular".